# Promise.resolve vs resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
         console.warn('Elo');
         resolve('First response');
      },
      1000);
})

promise1
.then((resp) => {
    console.warn('First then!');
    
});
```

And It resolves promise after one second going to then and console.warning 'First then!'.

But when I change line:

```
resolve('First response');
```

for

```
Promise.resolve('First response');
```

It won't work.
Some idea why ?

Also tried

```
return Promise.resolve('First response');
```

But it also doesn't work. I don't know why.

Can you help me understand it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `new Promise` constructor passes a specific function into your callback, which becomes your `resolve` parameter. That promise (the one you're constructing there with `new Promise`) can only be resolved by calling that specific `resolve` function.

`Promise.resolve` simply creates a new "pre-resolved" promise. It does not resolve any existing promise (nor would it have any way of knowing *which* promise it's supposed to resolve).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about it is:

Resolve === resolveCallback === first argument provided to your Promise callback
Promise.resolve === a function to returns a `new Promise`

These two are functional equivalents:

```
`const foo = Promise.resolve('First response').then( /* ... */ );`

`const bar = new Promise(function(resolveCallback, rejectCallback) {
    resolveCallback('First response');
  }).then( /* ... */ );`
```